# Function keys don't go to integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, key-bindings

I'm running an application in the integrated terminal that needs inputs of the <kbd>f1</kbd> - <kbd>f9</kbd> keys but some of those get captured by other things like the command-palette (<kbd>f1</kbd>). I have been looking around and found [issue #7269](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/7269), which implements this but I need the reverse of this. Is there any way to disable this? I tried adding `"terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": []`, to my settings but this did not seem to work.